# Is there a way to redirect the output of pv command to a file?

Tags: bash, pv

I need to redirect the output of pv command to a file so i get read it's progress from another process. Or is it any other way i could do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The progress info goes to standard error so have you tried `a | pv ... -f 2> /tmp/out | b`? Otherwise an adaptation of the more complicated example from the man page may be used:

```
( a | pv ... -f | b ) > /tmp/out 2>&1
```

Stdio buffering may present a problem.

Comment: I would like to emphasize the use of "-f".
From the man page
<quote>        -f, --force
              Force  output.   Normally, pv will not output any visual display if standard error is not a terminal.  This option forces it to do
              so.</quote>
This is particularly useful when using it with a job-scheduler (e.g., oarsub)